# Integrating Admob with ios application

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

Is it possible that I give admob id in one place in xcode and use it anywhere else in the code, just like in android studio strings implementations or do I need to provide it everytime I create admob ad

Comment: you can use the same id within same app at any position, any number of times.. However for analytics/tracking purposes always use different id per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your admob key in appDelegate to use in all ViewControllers check below steps:

- Create appDelegate shared instance using below code:

  ```
  static var sharedInstance : AppDelegate!
  ```
- Define your admob id like below:

  ```
  let adMobId = "abcd1234"
  ```
- Now you can use your admob id in any class with below code:

  ```
  AppDelegate.sharedInstance.adMobId
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Swift class with name Constants and assign values to  your admob_banner and admob_home like this

```
import Foundation

let admob_banner = "your banner id"
let admob_home = "your home id"
```

Now you can use these variables anywhere in your project